# Problem with using choice command - batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

i am trying to make character ("o") be able to enter both of the buldings, i've tried everything:

- detecting %pos% so when its 5 it goes to :fishing store
- adding "e" to choices so if i press e and %pos% equals 5 them goto :fishing store

(none of them worked, beacause i am doing something wrong and i don't know what)

ill be greatfull if someone will respond quickly

here is the code:

```
@echo off

title outside
mode 45,10
set/a pos=11

set "y7=[fishing]     [ fanta's ]"
set "y6=[ store ]     [  house  ]"
set "y5=H-------H     H---------H"
set "y4=H_II____H     H_II______H"
set "y3=H___[ ]_H__o__H___[ ]___H__________"
set "y2=::::::::::::::::::::::::H\/\/H\/\/H"
set "y1=::::::::::::::::::::::::H/\/\H/\/\H~~~~~~~~~~"

echo %y7%
echo %y6%
echo %y5%
echo %y4%
echo %y3%
echo %y2%
echo %y1%

goto movement

:movement
choice /c ad /n
if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto left
if %errorlevel% equ 2 goto right

:left
if %pos% gtr 1 set /a pos-=1
goto position

:right
if %pos% lss 32 set /a pos+=1
goto position

:position
if %pos% EQU 1 set "y3=o___[ ]_H_____H___[ ]___H__________" 
if %pos% EQU 2 set "y3=Ho__[ ]_H_____H___[ ]___H__________" 
if %pos% EQU 3 set "y3=H_o_[ ]_H_____H___[ ]___H__________"
if %pos% EQU 4 set "y3=H__o[ ]_H_____H___[ ]___H__________" 
if %pos% EQU 5 set "y3=H___[o]_H_____H___[ ]___H__________" 
if %pos% EQU 6 set "y3=H___[ ]oH_____H___[ ]___H__________" 
if %pos% EQU 7 set "y3=H___[ ]_o_____H___[ ]___H__________" 
if %pos% EQU 8 set "y3=H___[ ]_Ho____H___[ ]___H__________" 
if %pos% EQU 9 set "y3=H___[ ]_H_o___H___[ ]___H__________"
if %pos% EQU 10 set "y3=H___[ ]_H__o__H___[ ]___H__________" 
if %pos% EQU 11 set "y3=H___[ ]_H___o_H___[ ]___H__________"
if %pos% EQU 12 set "y3=H___[ ]_H____oH___[ ]___H__________" 
if %pos% EQU 13 set "y3=H___[ ]_H_____o___[ ]___H__________" 
if %pos% EQU 14 set "y3=H___[ ]_H_____Ho__[ ]___H__________"
if %pos% EQU 15 set "y3=H___[ ]_H_____H_o_[ ]___H__________"
if %pos% EQU 16 set "y3=H___[ ]_H_____H__o[ ]___H__________"
if %pos% EQU 17 set "y3=H___[ ]_H_____H___[o]___H__________" 
if %pos% EQU 18 set "y3=H___[ ]_H_____H___[ ]o__H__________" 
if %pos% EQU 19 set "y3=H___[ ]_H_____H___[ ]_o_H__________"
if %pos% EQU 20 set "y3=H___[ ]_H_____H___[ ]__oH__________"
if %pos% EQU 21 set "y3=H___[ ]_H_____H___[ ]___o__________" 
if %pos% EQU 22 set "y3=H___[ ]_H_____H___[ ]___Ho_________" 
if %pos% EQU 23 set "y3=H___[ ]_H_____H___[ ]___H_o________" 
if %pos% EQU 24 set "y3=H___[ ]_H_____H___[ ]___H__o_______" 
if %pos% EQU 25 set "y3=H___[ ]_H_____H___[ ]___H___o______" 
if %pos% EQU 26 set "y3=H___[ ]_H_____H___[ ]___H____o_____" 
if %pos% EQU 27 set "y3=H___[ ]_H_____H___[ ]___H_____o____" 
if %pos% EQU 28 set "y3=H___[ ]_H_____H___[ ]___H______o___" 
if %pos% EQU 29 set "y3=H___[ ]_H_____H___[ ]___H_______o__" 
if %pos% EQU 30 set "y3=H___[ ]_H_____H___[ ]___H________o_"
if %pos% EQU 31 set "y3=H___[ ]_H_____H___[ ]___H_________o"

:fanta's house
cls
echo you are at fanta's house
pause

:fishing store
cls
echo you are at fishing store 
pause

:print
cls
echo %y7% 
echo %y6%
echo %y5%
echo %y4%
echo %y3%
echo %y2%
echo %y1%
if %pos% EQU 5 choice /c ead /n >nul
if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto :fishing store
if %pos% EQU 17 choice /c ead /n >nul
if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto :fanta's house
if %errorlevel% equ 2 goto :left
if %errorlevel% equ 3 goto :right
goto movement
```

Comment: yes the same thing when %pos% is 17 but with diffrent label

Comment: @Gerhard u there?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure your file extension is `.cmd` and not `.bat`

Then something like this should help guide you.
Just replace your print section with this:

```
:print
cls
echo %y7% 
echo %y6%
echo %y5%
echo %y4%
echo %y3%
echo %y2%
echo %y1%
if %pos% EQU 5 choice /c ead /n >nul
if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto :fishingstore
if %errorlevel% equ 2 goto :left
if %errorlevel% equ 3 goto :right
if %pos% EQU 17 choice /c ead /n >nul
if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto :fantashouse
if %errorlevel% equ 2 goto :left
if %errorlevel% equ 3 goto :right
goto movement
```

As you seemed to have changed your original code, try this exact full version:

```
@echo off

title outside
mode 45,10
set/a pos=11

set "y7=[fishing]     [ fanta's ]"
set "y6=[ store ]     [  house  ]"
set "y5=H-------H     H---------H"
set "y4=H_II____H     H_II______H"
set "y3=H___[ ]_H__o__H___[ ]___H__________"
set "y2=::::::::::::::::::::::::H\/\/H\/\/H"
set "y1=::::::::::::::::::::::::H/\/\H/\/\H~~~~~~~~~~"

echo %y7%
echo %y6%
echo %y5%
echo %y4%
echo %y3%
echo %y2%
echo %y1%

goto movement

:movement
choice /c ad /n
if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto left
if %errorlevel% equ 2 goto right

:left
if %pos% gtr 1 set /a pos-=1
goto position

:right
if %pos% lss 32 set /a pos+=1
goto position

:position
if %pos% EQU 1 set "y3=o___[ ]_H_____H___[ ]___H__________" 
if %pos% EQU 2 set "y3=Ho__[ ]_H_____H___[ ]___H__________" 
if %pos% EQU 3 set "y3=H_o_[ ]_H_____H___[ ]___H__________"
if %pos% EQU 4 set "y3=H__o[ ]_H_____H___[ ]___H__________" 
if %pos% EQU 5 set "y3=H___[o]_H_____H___[ ]___H__________"
if %pos% EQU 6 set "y3=H___[ ]oH_____H___[ ]___H__________" 
if %pos% EQU 7 set "y3=H___[ ]_o_____H___[ ]___H__________" 
if %pos% EQU 8 set "y3=H___[ ]_Ho____H___[ ]___H__________" 
if %pos% EQU 9 set "y3=H___[ ]_H_o___H___[ ]___H__________"
if %pos% EQU 10 set "y3=H___[ ]_H__o__H___[ ]___H__________" 
if %pos% EQU 11 set "y3=H___[ ]_H___o_H___[ ]___H__________"
if %pos% EQU 12 set "y3=H___[ ]_H____oH___[ ]___H__________" 
if %pos% EQU 13 set "y3=H___[ ]_H_____o___[ ]___H__________" 
if %pos% EQU 14 set "y3=H___[ ]_H_____Ho__[ ]___H__________"
if %pos% EQU 15 set "y3=H___[ ]_H_____H_o_[ ]___H__________"
if %pos% EQU 16 set "y3=H___[ ]_H_____H__o[ ]___H__________"
if %pos% EQU 17 set "y3=H___[ ]_H_____H___[o]___H__________" 
if %pos% EQU 18 set "y3=H___[ ]_H_____H___[ ]o__H__________" 
if %pos% EQU 19 set "y3=H___[ ]_H_____H___[ ]_o_H__________"
if %pos% EQU 20 set "y3=H___[ ]_H_____H___[ ]__oH__________"
if %pos% EQU 21 set "y3=H___[ ]_H_____H___[ ]___o__________" 
if %pos% EQU 22 set "y3=H___[ ]_H_____H___[ ]___Ho_________" 
if %pos% EQU 23 set "y3=H___[ ]_H_____H___[ ]___H_o________" 
if %pos% EQU 24 set "y3=H___[ ]_H_____H___[ ]___H__o_______" 
if %pos% EQU 25 set "y3=H___[ ]_H_____H___[ ]___H___o______" 
if %pos% EQU 26 set "y3=H___[ ]_H_____H___[ ]___H____o_____" 
if %pos% EQU 27 set "y3=H___[ ]_H_____H___[ ]___H_____o____" 
if %pos% EQU 28 set "y3=H___[ ]_H_____H___[ ]___H______o___" 
if %pos% EQU 29 set "y3=H___[ ]_H_____H___[ ]___H_______o__" 
if %pos% EQU 30 set "y3=H___[ ]_H_____H___[ ]___H________o_"
if %pos% EQU 31 set "y3=H___[ ]_H_____H___[ ]___H_________o"
:print
cls
echo %y7% 
echo %y6%
echo %y5%
echo %y4%
echo %y3%
echo %y2%
echo %y1%
if %pos% EQU 5 choice /c ead /n >nul
if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto :fishingstore
if %pos% EQU 17 choice /c ead /n >nul
if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto :fantashouse
if %errorlevel% equ 2 goto :left
if %errorlevel% equ 3 goto :right
goto movement
goto :EOF

:fantashouse
cls
echo you are at fanta's house
choice /c ce /m "Continue or exit?"
if %errorlevel% equ 2 goto :print
pause
goto :EOF

:fishingstore
cls
echo you are at fishing store 
choice /c ce /m "Continue or exit?"
if %errorlevel% equ 2 goto :print
pause
goto :EOF
```

Comment: hold on... is your file extension `.bat` or `.cmd`? if `.bat`, please rename to `.cmd` and try again, it will work then,

Comment: THANKS!!! i dont know how it helped, but after changing file extention it worked

Comment: Personally, I see `.cmd` as the batch version of the tiles disaster. There is a tiny difference between the two - `if %pos% EQU 5 choice /c ead /n >nul` appears to leave `errorlevel` untouched for `bat` but changes it for `cmd`. It's not clear for the following `if %errorlevel%...` statement whether the `errorlevel` in question is that remaining from prior processing or from the `choice` that is optionally activated. It's subtleties like this that cause me to eschew `.cmd` and like the vast majority, stick with the known monster, `.bat`

Comment: `errorlevel` should reset the minute it is outside of it's scope, or when reset by another process @Magoo. `.cmd` handles this correctly though. I see `.bat` as it should be in the old `command.com` days, so I purely write `.cmd` files for the last few years (since Win 7 if memory serves me right).

Comment: So `cmd` has been doing it wrong for the last 26 years. eh?

Comment: No, that is not at all what I am saying, @Magoo , I am saying, `.cmd` files is an improvement to `.bat`

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

title outside
rem mode 45,10
set/a pos=11

:position
set "y3=H___[ ]_H_____H___[ ]___H__________"

SET /a y7=pos+1
CALL SET "y3=%%y3:~0,%pos%%%o%%y3:~%y7%%%"

set "y7=[fishing]     [ fanta's ]"
set "y6=[ store ]     [  house  ]"
set "y5=H-------H     H---------H"
set "y4=H_II____H     H_II______H"
set "y2=::::::::::::::::::::::::H\/\/H\/\/H"
set "y1=::::::::::::::::::::::::H/\/\H/\/\H~~~~~~~~~~"

cls
echo %y7%
echo %y6%
echo %y5%
echo %y4%
echo %y3%
echo %y2%
echo %y1%

:: goto movement

:movement
SET "choices=ad"
IF %pos% equ 5 SET "choices=ade"
IF %pos% equ 19 SET "choices=ade"
choice /c %choices% /n
if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto left
if %errorlevel% equ 2 goto right
IF %pos% equ 19 GOTO fanta's
IF %pos% equ 5 GOTO fishing

:left
if %pos% geq 1 set /a pos-=1
goto position

:right
if %pos% lss 32 set /a pos+=1
goto position


:fanta's house
cls
echo you are at fanta's house
pause
goto position

:fishing store
cls
echo you are at fishing store
pause
goto position


GOTO :EOF
```

A somewhat re-written version.

Since all that changes on the map is the position of `o`, place the `o` on the appropriate position on the line `y3`.

the first character in a string is "character 0" (hence, it's legitimate for `pos` to reach `0` - and `gtr` becomes `geq` in `left:`). Batch can substring using the syntax `var:~start,length` where `start` is the starting character number (or character-count from end, if negative) and `length` is number of characters (if negative, number of characters to not include).

So, we need to select that part of `y3` from the start to `pos`, then the `o` and then the remainder of `y3` starting at `pos+1`.

Hence - calculate `pos+1` as batch can't apply a calculation in the substring formula and put the result in a temporary variable. I chose `y7` since it's about to be reset anyway. and then use the parser to complete the extraction.

The parser examines `CALL SET "y3=%%y3:~0,%pos%%%o%%y3:~%y7%%%"` and replaces, left-to-right (let's assume `pos=11`, hence `y7=12`) `%%` with `%` and `%var%` with `var's value` since the `set` is being `call`ed:

```
set "y3=% y3:~0, 11 % o % y3:~ 12 %" (spaces inserted to show parser's steps)
set "y3=%y3:~0,11%o%y3:~12%" (as executed)
```

which places the `o` appropriately, depending on `pos`.

Our next step is whether `o` is at position 5 or 19 (not 17), when we need to allow `e` as well as `a` and `d` in the `choice`. Simply append the `e` in these circumstances, and `choice` will yield `errorlevel` 1 for `a`, 2 for `d` and 3 for `e` (but only if `e` is one of the choices).

Then - well, if `choice` has returned errorlevel `1` or `2`, go left/right and if it's neither of those, then it must be `3`, so `e` was pressed and we can look at `pos` to see which of the two routines to jump to.

Note that a label can't contain spaces, so if you tried `fanta's house` `fanta's shop` and `fanta's tennis court` then only the label `fanta's` would be interpreted (it's unusual, but not invalid, to use `'` in a label). `cmd` would search for the next label `fanta's` following the `goto` as its destination, which might give the illusion of working correctly - but that's a trap...